# Is every Promise-chain -> try/catch/await guide teaching a dangerous convention?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, try-catch

Every example I've seen of going from error-catching Promise chains to try/catch/await look like this:

```
class Api {
  static getUserPhones(userObj) {
    console.log(userObj.phones.length)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('err'))
  }
}
const user = { id: 123, phones: [] }

/** Turn this... */
Api.getUserPhones(user.id) // user.id is a mistake
 .then(resp => console.log(resp))
 .catch(err => console.error('network error:', err))

/** ...into this! */
try {
  const resp = await Api.getUserPhones(user.id) // user.id is a mistake
  console.log(resp)
} catch (err) {
  console.error('network error:', err)
}
```

But this is not safe at worst, and setting us up for bugs at best. Any `TypeError`, `ReferenceError`, `SyntaxError`, `RangeError`, etc that could have happened either within `Api.getUser()` or even in the parms passed to it (`user.wrong.id`), gets unexpectedly swallowed in the `try` block. Unless your code will always be free of mistakes, converting your code to `try/catch` like the examples could make finding errors and debugging them really challenging.

As an extreme example, if a guide told us to put *all* your code in a `try`, that guide would be wrong IMO. Everything can throw, even if not designed to, and we should only use `try` when our code throws by design.

Am I missing something? Is everyone just writing riskier code and not knowing it?

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume that the code is sane (eg, returns a Promise instead of throwing), though it's true they're not exactly equivalent.

Comment: It's incredibly foolish to assume that everything inside `Api.getUser()`, is and always will be, free of javascript Errors.

Comment: "But this is not safe" Of course not, there are no semicolons to protect you! In all seriousness though, it would be good if you clarified what you mean by "safe" and "unsafe". Do you consider the transformed code inherently unsafe for some reason, or is it just that it isn't an exact equivalent of the original?

Comment: There's no need to be condescending. I would like others to not fall into the same holes that I just have, and to make sure that I'm understanding the problem, overcome it in a consistent way, and see if other people have other solutions to avoid these kinds of errors. I'm attempting to make sure that I have gathered enough knowledge on the topic before I tell other people of the risks that they may be unknowingly taking on. Isn't that part of the point of SO? Help each other write better code?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the two code snippets are not always 100% identical in behaviour does not make either of them unsafe. It just makes them different in a particular edge case. In the end it's your call as the code author whether this edge case needs to be preserved or not.

That said, the proper equivalent would just have the promise be obtained outside the try/catch:

```js
const promise = Api.getUser(user.id)
try {
  const resp = await promise
  console.log(resp)
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

However, from here we can make some modifications depending on what assumptions we can make. E.g., if we know that `Api.getUser(user.id)` doesn't throw, then it is perfectly valid to call `Api.getUser(user.id)` inside the `try` block instead.

As a minor aside, I'd also like to address a comment on the question:

> It's incredibly foolish to assume that everything inside Api.getUser(), is and always will be, free of javascript Errors

This is a strong assertion, and it also happens to be plainly false. First of all, let's be clear that not everything inside `Api.getUser()` needs to be free of errors. So long as any errors are handled inside `Api.getUser()` the caller may still be free from handling these errors. And secondly, if `Api.getUser()` is documented to not throw, then it would be a **very reasonable** thing to expect it to not throw. Otherwise, you have to make the judgment call whether it even matters if it can throw or not, and whether those errors need to be treated any differently then the errors propagated through the promise.

Comment: 1. "if we know that Api.getUser(user.id) doesn't throw". Everything 'can' throw, unless you write perfect code. 2. "So long as any errors are handled inside Api.getUser()". Would you write a try/catch inside Api.getUser() JUST to handle potential `TypeError`s? I certainly wouldn't. I'd write code the way it's meant to work, and let errors propagate up if the caller uses the function incorrectly.

Comment: "Everything 'can' throw, unless you write perfect code." Perfection isn't required. And automated tests and other tools can help you out a lot. "Would you write a try/catch inside Api.getUser() JUST to handle potential TypeErrors?" Maybe. Or maybe I have sufficient type checking to avoid the possibility of TypeErrors. "I certainly wouldn't." Glad you decided that. But the fact that you wouldn't do so does not preclude someone else from doing it, nor does it make it unreasonable.

Comment: "I'd write code the way it's meant to work, and let errors propagate up if the caller uses the function incorrectly." Sure, propagating those errors is a perfectly fine choice. But "meant" to work depends on the design of the function in question. If the author means for it to not throw errors based on inputs, then throwing errors is not how it is meant to work.

Comment: Regarding user input, keep in mind that `Api.getUser()` itself may not care about the type of input. E.g., any validation could already be happening under the promise rather than in `Api.getUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

The way `try/catch` blocks works is that if there is any error thrown within the `try` block, it will be handled in the `catch` block.

The answer is no, they are not wrong.

`TypeError`s are not 'swallowed'.  They are handled just like any other error.
Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpqwoy0d/2/) illustrating this.

Comment: You're missing the point.

Comment: @KFunk Maybe you should clarify what you mean.

Answer (score -3):

It seems like guides should be telling us to write:

```
const annoyingPromiseVar = Api.getUserPhones(user.id) // behaves like promise chains. won't hide Errors
try {
  const resp = await annoyingPromiseVar
  console.log(resp)
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Comment: you are misunderstanding async and await